# In a week versus After a week

Tags: phrase-usage

"I'll be back **in a week**" means "I'll be back after a week has passed" or "I'll be back after the next seven day's period is over".

I was very much wondering if "I'll be back **after a week**" is also valid. I've done a ton of research only to fail to come up with any answers.

If it is, does the "after a week" version mean just about the same thing as the "in a week" version? Are they, I mean, interchangeable?

Or does the "after a week" version have a slightly different meaning, like **"I'll only be back after a week has passed"** or **"I won't be back until a week has passed"**?

Or is it just that few English speakers have chosen to use it irregardless of its being perfectly grammatical as well as logical?

Answer (score 1):

*In a week* means exactly after a one-week period, except in those cases where "a week" is being used an approximate time period.

*After a week* could mean more than a one-week period.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any difference between in or after  a week.

> **I will be back in a week**
>
> **I will be back  after a week**

Both the sentences mean that he will come after the completion of a week.